# Nodejs API deploy to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, heroku, deployment

I'm like for 2 days stuck in trying to deploy this Nodejs API to Heroku (and the irony/joke: it's working on my machine! Believe me! LOL). I've got many and many errors before, but I apparently fixed them all, except this one now:

```
2021-08-12T02:33:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user xxxx@hotmail.com
2021-08-12T02:34:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-08-12T02:34:31.051122+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 51176bf9 by user xxxxx@hotmail.com
2021-08-12T02:34:31.051122+00:00 app[api]: Release v38 created by user xxxxxx@hotmail.com
2021-08-12T02:34:32.043979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-12T02:34:36.299607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-08-12T02:34:40.689105+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-12T02:34:40.689147+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app
2021-08-12T02:34:40.689147+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./dist/index.js
2021-08-12T02:34:40.689148+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925689+00:00 app[web.1]: file:///app/dist/index.js:5
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925709+00:00 app[web.1]: Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925710+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925711+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925711+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925717+00:00 app[web.1]: This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/app/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925721+00:00 app[web.1]: at file:///app/dist/index.js:5:23
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925726+00:00 app[web.1]: at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:170:25)
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925727+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
2021-08-12T02:34:40.925727+00:00 app[web.1]: at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
2021-08-12T02:34:40.978104+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-08-12T02:34:40.983071+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-08-12T02:34:40.992651+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node ./dist/index.js`
2021-08-12T02:34:40.992928+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-08-12T02:34:40.993242+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-08-12T02:34:40.993515+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.
2021-08-12T02:34:40.993715+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-08-12T02:34:41.004082+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-12T02:34:41.004085+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-08-12T02:34:41.004086+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-08-12T02_34_40_994Z-debug.log
2021-08-12T02:34:41.074430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-12T02:34:41.154351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've tried a lot of things, but for what I know I can't use this suggested solution because I'm using Typescript and using "import (...)", so I need to keep the `"type": "module"` and the `"module": "commonjs"`...

Here's my current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/server.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --pretty --transpile-only ./src/index.ts",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

And this is my current tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {                        /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ESNEXT",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "dist",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

It's my 1st time deploying to Heroku, but I've read a lot from the official docs, foruns and nothing seems to work...

I'm using Github connected to Heroku and this integration seems to work all fine.

Oh, and here's my index.ts:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
import helmet from 'helmet';
import express from "express";
import portfolioRouter from "./routes/portfolio-routes";
import teamRouter from "./routes/team-routes";

dotenv.config();
let PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10);
console.log("PORT: ", PORT);

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/v1/portfolio", portfolioRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/team", teamRouter);

console.log("PORT being used: ", PORT);

app.listen(PORT || 8080, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Anyone?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I created a new really simple node API, with just a server.ts with an app.get route returning a string. But this time I didn't enable github deployment. I just used Heroku git. After getting it working all fine, I started to move my previous code to this new project and from this time on everything started to work just fine.

My API is on!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `"module":"commonjs"` to `"module":"es6"`